# I am not getting output for map widget in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, arcgis

I am working on Jupyter Notebook and installed ArcGis api. When I called the map from that api then map widget is not showing. All the features of arcgis api is working quite well, except it's map widget.

> Following is the code:-

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
myGIS = GIS()
myGIS.map()
```

> The above mentioned code is showing only the following :-

```
MapView(layout=Layout(height='400px', width='100%'))
A world map should appear, but it's only showing a line of text i.e; 
"MapView(layout=Layout(height='400px', width='100%'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure widgets are enabled.

See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html

Comment: Yes, I was using this on Mozilla when tried on Chrome it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome was my answer. Everyting is working fine, as long as Chrome is the browser. Cheers.